# Is Caprice treated as a false deity in Islam

Tags: allah

If I take Caprice as my partial path also follow Islam to certain extent will I be associating partners with Allah?

> Quran 45:23 Hast thou seen him who has taken his **caprice** to be his god, and God has led him astray out of a knowledge, and set a seal upon his hearing and his heart, and laid a covering on his eyes? Who shall guide him after God? What, will you not remember?

Answer (score 2):

The verse you quoted may also be translated into:

> Have you seen he who has **taken as his god his [own] desire**, and Allah has sent him astray due to knowledge and has set a seal upon his hearing and his heart and put over his vision a veil? So who will guide him after Allah ? Then will you not be reminded?

or as Muhammed Asad translates it:

> HAST THOU ever considered [the kind of man] who makes **his own desires his deity**,

In [Tafsir Tabari](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/45/al-djathiyah/23/al-tabari) it is mentioned that a man from among the polytheists used to worship a stone, and when he saw a better (stone) than it, he threw the old away and started to worship the other:

> شهوتَه التـي يهواها وذلك أن الرجل من الـمشركين كان يعبد الـحجر، فإذا رأى أحسن منه رمى به، وأخذ الآخر يعبده، فكان معبوده وإلهه ما يتـخيره لنفسه

In [Tafisr Zamakhshari](http://altafasir.com/al-quran/surat/45/al-djathiyah/23/al-zamakhshari), he explains it as: "He is obedient to the lusts of his self: He follows his self wherever it beckons him, as if he serves him as one should serve one's God.

#### Conclusion

In this context, it is most probably that the explanation of the verse is relevant to the polytheists who follows their desires to choose a god that fits their desires. With other word it is as if they take their own desires as a god.

Comment: Zamakshari close to atheist version of god

Comment: Well, some might interpret it that way, it is a possibility to do so, but it is clear in the Arabic tafsir that Zamakshari is talking about the man who took stones as gods, just as tabari said. If you continue to read Zamakshari in Arabic you will notice it is the same story: "لأنه كان يستحسن الحجر فيعبده، فإذا رأى ما هو أحسن رفضه إليه، فكأنه اتخذ هواه آلهة شتى"

Comment: @Preordainment Atheists have no version of god, they just don't buy into any of the ones on offer.

Comment: You should listen to Ali ataie talks on atheism, he points this verse for them

Answer (score -2):

As far as your question is concerned, There is only One Being, which is treated as a Deity or God in Islam. That is **Allah**. And none other than the **Allah** is treated as a Deity.
As the Islamic Kalmah says: **لآ اِلَهَ اِلّا اللّهُ مُحَمَّدٌ رَسُوُل اللّهِ**
Translation: **There is No God but Allah and Muhammad(PBUH) is his Messenger**.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We are not a typical an internet forum. Therefore we expect answers to be well elaborated, see "[how to answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)" for more information. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model.

Comment: Added false deity to improve question